# Getting the following error : Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting this error: 
Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
I think I have written the statement correctly and the number of parameters are also same. Please correct me.

```
function Hello($questionId){
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        SELECT 
        id,
        answerby ,
        answer,
        questionId
        FROM ".$db_table_prefix."answers 
        WHERE `questionid` = 1
        ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$questionId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $answerby, $answer,$questionId);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row = array('id' => $id, 'answerby' => $answerby, 'answer' => $answer, 'questionId' => $questionId);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $row;

}
```

Comment: You have no binder placeholders in your SQL statement.... should be `WHERE \`questionId\` = ?`

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE questionid= 1` to `WHERE questionid= ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the code so that it can work.

function Hello($questionId){

```
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        SELECT 
        id,
        answerby ,
        answer,
        questionId
        FROM ".$db_table_prefix."answers 
        WHERE `questionid` = ?
        ");

    $stmt->bind_param("i",$questionId);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $answerby, $answer,$questionId);

    while ($stmt->fetch()){

        $row = array('id' => $id, 'answerby' => $answerby, 'answer' => $answer, 'questionId' => $questionId);

    }

    $stmt->close();
    return $row;

}
```

Comment: It's not working.
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: Sorry, mistook it for PDO. Try it now, I edited the question.